# Which Ubuntu version to install?

Tags: downloads

My laptop configuration: Windows 7 - 32 bit - Intel Pentium 2.1 Ghz Dual Core - 2 GB RAM - 320GB HDD (for software development and also for practice).

Comment: You can install any 32-bit Ubuntu version. 14.04 LTS or 15.04.

Comment: Is your shift key damaged?

Answer (score 1):

**Recommended Minimum System Requirements**

Ubuntu Desktop Edition :

- 700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
- 512 MiB RAM (system memory)
- 5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
- VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
- Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
- Internet access is helpful

(The [Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements))